Managing Location-Based 3D Models in Flutter: A Pokémon Go-Inspired Approach
In Flutter, what is the most effective way to maintain 3D model files (in GLB format) at specific locations? For example, similar to how it's done in Pokemon Go, I want to display 3D models at certain locations in my application. How can I manage the location information (coordinates) of these files, and what approach should I take to allow users to interactively view these 3D models?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
